# sqlite, как определить доступное место в бд

Tags: sqlite

Как определить доступное место  в файле?

Из вывода sqlite3_analyzer, вижу:

```
Size of the file in bytes......................... 5633162240
Bytes of user payload stored...................... 2175214328  38.6%
```

Bytes of user payload stored - это свободное место?

После vacuum, файл базы данных уменьшился всего на 5 мегабайт, а значение в Bytes of user payload stored остался прежним.

Т.е., как узнать, что в файле есть место, чтобы провести вакум?

А .dump базы, уменьшил файл на 1 гб.

Answer (score 1):

freelist page count более менее актуальную информацию показывает, т.е.:

```
sqlite>.dbinfo
database page size:  1024
write format:        1
read format:         1
reserved bytes:      0
file change counter: 1067285
database page count: 2598894
freelist page count: 2168223
```